# HTML image rollover : fade in to the left or right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im using this code to make mouse over changing button

got the code from this website

```
http://helplogger.blogspot.com/2012/05/create-rollover-image-effect-change.html
```

Code im using:

```
<a href="Blog"><img src="images/menu/dflt_blog_btn.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/menu/rlovr_blog_btn.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/menu/dflt_blog_btn.png'" /></a>
```

Is it possible to make it fade in, rather than just change over? if so how can i do it?

this might be stupid but if we can make it fade in can we make it fade in to the left or right ????

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using,

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('a').hover(function(){
          $(this).stop().find('img').hide()
          .attr('src','img1.jpg').fadeIn();
      },function(){
          $(this).stop().find('img').hide()
          .attr('src','img2.jpg').fadeIn();
     });
  })
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/4Kf6z/)

Comment: Thanks m8... one more question how do i implement this to my HTML page
this looks like jquery

Comment: @Malinda Download jquery.js from Jquery.com. Just give a reference to that js file as similar to other js files and copy this snippet paste inside the script tag. You are done. :)

Comment: Im sorry to be a pain whats the HTML bit that i have to use inside the div???

sorry for my noobness :D and thanks a million

Comment: @Malinda Have you seen the demo.? it has html too. You just need to wrap them in a normal html layout.

Comment: im a tad bit confused brother

can i use this on my HTML code. 

i added your js. then the images started to disappear on mouse hover

Comment: @Malinda Do you have Jquery library.?

Comment: Im running Jquery 2.03 with the jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js

it already being used for the image sliders and working fine